# Appending value to array at endpoint in JSON server

Tags: javascript, typescript, rest

I am working with the [JSON server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) npm application and I am defining endpoints for a simple application. My intention is to create a POST request endpoint which updates or replaces a single element in an array. To do this I have implemented this code so far.

```js
server.use((req, res, next) => {

    const TEST_CASE_PATH = 'tf-test-cases'

    if (req.path == `/${TEST_CASE_PATH}`){

        else if (req.method === 'POST') {
            console.log('MADE A POST REQUEST!')

            const newTC = req.body as TestCase
            console.log(newTC)
            let testCases = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(router.db.get(TEST_CASE_PATH))) as TestCase[]

            for (let i = 0; i < testCases.length; i++){
                const testCase = testCases[i];
                if (newTC.uuid == testCase.uuid){
                    testCases[i] = newTC;
                    // update db old test case with new test case
                    // send user new test case as response
                    return;
                }
            }

            testCases.push(newTC)
            // update db with new test case
            // send user new test case as response
            res.send(testCases); 
            return;
        }

        else if (req.method == 'DELETE') {
            console.log('MADE A DELETE REQUEST!')
            res.send({req: "delete"})

        }
    }

    else {
        // Continue to JSON Server router
        next()
    }
})
```

If this is not so clear what I am intending to do, my goal is to query the db at the endpoint `TEST_CASE_PATH`, find if the uuid of the TestCase object in the request body that is equal to any that are existing, if so replace it and publish the new list of TestCase object to the db, else, push the new TestCase to the list and publish the new list to the DB.

My question is: My database is not updating with the new test cases, the response is correct so I am certain that the add/modify list entry logic is working. How would I write the updated TestCase[] list to the db at the endpoint?

Thanks in advance. I hope that the solution is not trivial. I have searched [the repo](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) as well as other stack overflow questions but I can not seem to find an answer. I don't have an option but to use this as its for a simple DB at work.

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution:

```js
if (req.path == '/tf-test-cases'){

    const TEST_CASE_PATH = 'tf-test-cases'

    else if (req.method === 'POST') {
        console.log('MADE A POST REQUEST!')

        const newTC = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body)) as TestCase
        let testCases = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(router.db.get(TEST_CASE_PATH))) as TestCase[]

        for (let i = 0; i < testCases.length; i++){
            const testCase = testCases[i];
            if (newTC.uuid == testCase.uuid){
                console.log('updating tc')
                testCases[i] = newTC;
                // update db old test case with new test case
                router.db.set(TEST_CASE_PATH, testCases).write()
                // send user new test case as response
                res.send(newTC)
                return;
            }
        }

        testCases.push(newTC)
        // update db with new test case
        router.db.set(TEST_CASE_PATH, testCases).write()
        // send user new test case as response
        res.send(testCases); 
        return;
    }
}
```